# WP_Query variables not resetting with the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is a scenario:
I have 3 queries
First query returns products by current user

```
$current_user_products = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'author' => get_current_user_id() ) );
foreach($custom_user_products->posts as $custom_user_product) {
}
```

Now second query returns posts which has a meta key with product id

```
$custom_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => ['custom_post'] ) );
foreach($custom_posts->posts as $custom_post) {
            $rel_post = get_post_meta($custom_post->ID, 'ProductID', true);
}
```

Now the 3rd query is for the same custom_post type, but it only returns posts which match the first query.
Here's a code that would make it more clear

```
if ($rel_post == $current_user_product) {
                $matching_id = $custom_post->ID;
}
$third_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => ['custom_post'], 'p' => $matching_ids ) );
enter code here
```

The problem I am facing is that the third query only returns 1 post.
I need help with the code so I can fix this problem

Comment: Welcome Mr Wick :) your third code block shows an assignment to `$matching_id` and `$third_query` uses `$matching_ids` is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I think that happens because you use
'p' => $matching_ids
Key 'p' in WP_Query expects one concrete post_id and query with this param always returns only one wp_post.
And there is another error in code $matching_ids  in this code always will contain only one ID but this variable should contain an array of post_ids

```
if ($rel_post == $current_user_product) {
                $matching_id = $custom_post->ID;
}
```

You should use 'post__in' instead of 'p' and $matching_ids must be an array

```
$third_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => ['custom_post'], 'post__in' => $matching_ids ) );
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to convert $matching_ids to array?

Comment: I don't know, I assume you should have some loop in your code where you collect some IDs into this array
loop starts 
if ($rel_post == $current_user_product) {
                $matching_id[] = $custom_post->ID;
}
loop ends 
 $matching_id[] - array of some posts_ids